# Magnetic induction vs?

Tags: electromagnetism

Electromagnetic fields must have a source. That source can be a current density or a charge density. When an electric field results from a time varying current we call this phenomenon “magnetic induction”. When an electric field results from a charge density what do we call that phenomenon? Seems to me it should have a name too.

Comment: As far as I know, it doesn't have a name since we intuitively assign a electric field to a charge density (like we assign a magnetic field to a current density).

Answer (score 0):

@Charlie comment holds for static charge and current densities only, where electrostatics is completely separated from magnetostatics. 
When currents or/and charges are varying in time, you can in principle no longer separate them, but this remains a good approximation at low frequencies)

Magnetic induction (according to Faraday's law) is a specific case where you take into account that a varing magnetic field induces (creates) an electric field, but neglect the reverse phenomenon (that is to say the creation of a magnetic field by a varying electric field). This approximation is named "magnetic quasipermanent regime approximation".

Hence, in this regime, you could distinguish between "electrostatic" electric field created by charges and "induced" electric field (ofen also termed as "electromotive" field) the one resulting  from the time varying magnetic field created by the mean of time varying currents.

Please notice that this dictincton loose its meaning when you go at higher frequency where the so called "displacement current" introduced by Maxwell must be taken into account.